# Snapcraft python builds - how to get it to pack - path doesn’t exist error?

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04, snapcraft

So I am newer to Snapcraft, however I have been having this issue, despite following examples and tutorials so I figured I would ask here.

**Machine setup**: So I am on a windows machine, running ubuntu in a VM to compile the snap. Sadly work has not given me a ubuntu dev machine. Our deployments are on linux machines (hence the need for a snap), but they gave me a windows machine.

**Snap Problem**: Have a file (main.py) that is normally launched as “python3 -m main” and we want to make it into a snap.

So far I have this as my snap:

```
name: asdf
version: '4.0.0'
summary: asdf
description: |
    qweradsf - blah-etc...
grade: devel
confinement: devmode
base: core22

parts:
  py-dep:
    plugin: python
    source: .
    python-packages:
      - pyserial
      - ftputil

apps:
  asdf:
    command: usr/bin/python -m main
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: $SNAP/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:${SNAP}/usr/local/lib
```

For the command part I have tried all the combinations below

```
command: usr/bin/python -m main
command: /usr/bin/python -m main
command: /bin/python -m main
(also tried the above eith /usr/lib/python path)
command: python -m main
command: python3 -m main
```

When it goes to pack the snap file, I will get the error that the first argument - usr, bin, python, python3 - path doesn’t exist. Also tried adding PYTHONPATH. Nothing seems to work.

How do I call this python code? Do I need a source? Examples I saw didn’t use a source for the plugin (just had the . ), so I have been leaving that part mostly alone.

Comment: Looking at how you set PYTHONPATH, it seems that `$SNAP` belongs at the front of all the paths.  So did you try `command: $SNAP/usr/bin/python -m main` ?

Comment: It also doesn't exist.

Comment: So I tried to build the example project found here: https://snapcraft.io/docs/python-apps and I also get the same issue. So it looks like an issue with my SNAP setup, rather then my project.

Answer (score 0):

So there were a couple issues.

1. it's `bin/python` for the path. Make sure there is no / before it.
2. After running into the issue with the same project, I ran `snapcraft clean` everywhere I could.

After that no issues. Strongly recommend the clean command if you start seeing pathing issues.